# AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by server

Tags: android, audio, low-latency

There are several questions about the error

> AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client

I could find none about the flag being denied *by server*:
I got the "denied by client error" by using .wav raw files sampled ad 44.1kHz. Then resampled them at 48k and now I get this:

> V/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by server; frameCount
>   180000​

Comment: Have you figured this out?